# Jquery Datatable-Average in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using jquery data table for showing output.There i have a case,i want to show average of a column in footer row.How can i achieve this??

Comment: if you don't get a javascript solution from an expert, you can calculate the average at the source (by iterating through the datasource etc) and put it in the footer. I did it to add avgs and sums to the header. works like a charm!

Comment: @Farhan Ahmed..can u pls share sample code

Comment: Because you haven't responded to the question below I am putting sample code in as an answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code to show average in Footer for Datatable Plugin:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    fnFooterCallback: function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
        var TotalMarks = 0;
        for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
        {
            TotalMarks += aaData[i][2]*1;
        }

        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
        nCells[1].innerHTML = TotalMarks/aaData.length;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My project is ASP.Net MVC so in the controller I put something like

> DataTable dt=GetRequiredData(); double sumField1=0; double
>   sumField2=0; double avgField1=0;
>
> foreach(DataRow r in dt) {    sumField1 +=
>   Convert.ToDouble(r["Field1"]);    sumField2 +=
>   Convert.ToDouble(r["Field2"]);    avgField1 +=
>   Convert.ToDouble(r["Field3"]); }
>
> avgField1 /= dt.Rows.Count;
>
> ViewBag.sumField1=sumField1.ToString();
>   ViewBag.sumField2=sumField2.ToString();
>   ViewBag.avgField1=avgField1.ToString();

then in the View I put

> Sum Field (@Viewbag.sumField1) Sum Field2
>   (@Viewbag.sumField2) Avg Field (@Viewbag.avgField1)

Needless to say the  is part of a jQuery Datatable.
Got a thumbs up from my boss on this ;)